# C# Binding treeview to list of nested structure

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, treeview

I am trying to bind list of level 3 to treeview in wpf mvvm. I get this list by calling function in model class. I have class structure like below.

```
namespace Projectname.Model
{
 class Gate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; }
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string GateMode { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
};

class Floor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Gate> Gates { get; set; }
};

 class Building
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Floor> Floors { get; set; }
};
}
```

Below is what i have tried. Here i don't know how to give datatype.

```
      <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Buildings}" Margin="10" Height="200">
                    <TreeView.Resources>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Buildings}" DataType="{x:Type local:Building}">
                            <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

                    </TreeView.Resources>

                </TreeView>
```

Properties

```
    Window x:Class="projectname.MainWindow"
    xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:projectname.Model"
```

I am able to display building names but like one below other not like tree
as shown in image below.
[image]

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the templates in the `<TreeView.Resources>` and you have to speficy them not nested.

For example this could be look like (as an example just for `Floor` and `Door`).

```
<TreeView.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Floor}" ItemsSource="{Binding Gates}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Floors}" DataType="{x:Type local:Building}">
        <TextBlock Header="{Binding Name}"/>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Gate}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

If you have a node which can have children use a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and set's `DataType` to the class it should show and the `ItemsSource` to the collection with children.

**Important**

Your `Door`, `Floor`, etc structs have to be `public` and no nested and I would recommend using classes instead.

With this example data

```
new Floor
{
    Name = "Floor 1",
    Doors = new List<Door>
    {
        new Door { Name = "Door 1"},
        new Door {Name = "Door 2" }
    }
},
new Floor
{
    Name = "Floor 2",
    Doors = new List<Door>
    {
        new Door { Name = "Door 3"},
        new Door {Name = "Door 4" }
    }
}
```

it'll look like

[image: Example]

**edit namespace problem**

You have to specify the namespace in your xaml.

For example your `Floor` is in the namespace `MyProject.ViewModel` you have to add `xmlns:something="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"` in your xaml and use `DataType="{x:Type something:Floor}"` in your template.

**edit**

Change

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:projectname.Model"
```

to

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CentralizedControlHMI.Model"
```

And make `Floor`, `Gate`, etc `public` because the default is `private`.

```
public class Floor
```

Comment: floor is not available in local as i am creating this window which displays the sturcture in viewmodel and i give data context there only. Also please see the structure now. its like door inside floor and floor inside building. Thanks

Comment: Make it oublic and the type will be available. And don't make it nested inside another class. It does not matter where the instances are created.

Comment: @RPK Edited my answer: added example data and example output with the code I've provided.

Comment: I am able to access the data now. I will go forward and try to implement as you suggested

Comment: @RPK Good luck, if you need more help just let me know.

Comment: If i type local and : i get all floor and gate class but after i set it, I get error as the floor does not exist in namespace.

Comment: Have you tried closing the xaml window and rebuilding? Sometimes that helps. Otherwise: in which namespace is your `Floor` and in which is your xaml window?

Comment: The structures are in model. Outside class and public. I have include the model folder which contains all the model classes

Comment: I have converted structs to class and i have already included model folder from my project. That is why i am able to access classes when i type local:but still getting error.

Comment: @RPK Sorry but I can't do anything else without the information I have. Add your full `Floor` class including namespace and the content (namespace) or the `x:Class` property of your xaml `Window`. And the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for your `Floor` to the question and we'll find out about the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151728/discussion-between-rpk-and-mighty-badaboom).

Comment: @RPK I'm not at a pc anymore, just mobile

Comment: @RPK You need another `HierarchicalDataTemplate` for the `Floor` and a `DataTemplate` for the `Gate` like I did in my answer.

Comment: I don't know how to add them one inside other. As said in edited question i have list which i am getting from model to view model which has all data. If you can edit your answer according to the list and three levels that would be great. Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer (have a look at the first part). You should read something about the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` and how it's working. The `ItemsSource` should be set to the child collection like in my example. And you don't have to encapsulate the templates. They do it automatically for you.

Comment: What exactly is Floors and Gates used in itemsource binding? and are you binding building in treeview tool?As  i Said i gave an nested list of building,floor and gates then how do i bind floor in `HierarchicalDataTemplate `

Comment: I got it. Thanks for your help